# How to overlay frames before making a gif FFMPEG WEBM TO GIF

Tags: ffmpeg, command-line, png, gif, webm

I'm using windows batch to do some ffmpeg work

Basically what I need to do is this

**Add an overlay every X frames (10 in this example, 1, 11 , 21 and so on) to a webm source to a gif.**

The how doesn't really matter as long as I keep the quality of my current palette/filter/dither usage

Solution I found:  I made a Video to png, overlay the png with batch for loop and make a gif

Problem I encountered: Gif doesn't work with the overlayed pngs

```
rem EXTRACTING
ffmpeg !time_range! -i "input.webm" -vsync 0 -vf "fps=20,scale=!size!" "output_%%03d.png"
```

the two %% is because you need to escape it in batch so ffmpeg sees "%03d"

```
REM OVERLAYING
for %%i in (_*1.png) do (
ffmpeg -y -v error -i %%i -i %tmp_blank_frame% -filter_complex "overlay"  overlayed_%%~nxi
del %%i
)
REM REPLACING
rename "overlayed_*" "//////////*"
```

It is not pretty by any means, but it works... somewhat.

It does it's job of overlaying and renaming proprely, but when I recompile the frames into a gif with

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 20 -i "output_%%03d.png" -i "!palette!" -filter_complex "!filters! [v]; [v][1:v] paletteuse=dither=!dither!" "overlayedgif.gif"
```

it just gives me an error "Error marking filters as finished" and does nothing.

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 20 -i "output_%%03d.png" -i "!palette!" "overlayedgif.gif"
```

It makes the gif without the black frames (skips them) also terrible quality

I am open to any suggestion. Pretty new to this whole ffmpeg and this is starting to be very complicated for me so there might be some code that I overlook or don't fully understand

Important note  ***IF I REMOVE THE OVERLAY/RENAME BLOCK MY SCRIPT WORKS WONDERS!!!***

EDIT : edited confusing variables im using in my script

Comment: No need to decompose to images. Conditional overlay possible upon video.

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg 
-i OG.mp4 
-i frame.png 
-y -filter_complex "overlay=enable='eq(mod(n,10),0)+eq(n,0)'" 
overlayed.mp4
```

change `'eq(mod(n,10),0)+eq(n,0)'` to your liking but, this is exactly what Q is about.

You can read more on FFMPEG's arithmetic and expressions over here  https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation

I'm not sure you can do webm-to-gif in one go with the overlay and paletteuse, I will edit if I find out